# What's the meaning of "get in" in "get in the spirit of Valentine's day"?

Tags: meaning

"Get in" has the meaning of "arrive". But I think it can have other meanings.
Please see the following sentence:

> Please get in the spirit of Valentine's day here in Costa coffee shop.

Here what does "get in" mean?

Comment: “Get in” has several meanings, and “arrive” is actually one of the less common ones (used primarily in the idiom “When did you get in?” which abbreviates “When did you get into town/here?”).

Comment: In this case, it means to abstractly “get into” (put yourself into) a particular state of mind.

Comment: See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21884/whats-the-meaning-of-in-the-spirit-of

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes *get in* also used as *get into*, see the examples [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+in), in your case, it means get into the particular mental state, i.e. the spirit of Valentine's day here in costa coffee shop.

Answer (score -1):

It directs the listener to acquire something they now lack, implying they may still join the group if they do so.